# Please synonymize and merge [rss-reader] and [feed-reader]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

[rss-reader](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss-reader) and [feed-reader](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feed-reader) cover the same territory. (There are questions about Feedly in both, for instance.)

The former has more questions than the latter. However, by its name "rss-reader" would seem to exclude things that consume Atom feeds. Then again, I don't see any new syndication formats coming along any time soon and anyone who knows about Atom knows about RSS as well.

In other words, I don't have strong feelings about which tag should be the "master". But they should be merged and synonymized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have merged [feed-reader](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feed-reader) in to [rss-reader](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss-reader) and made [rss-reader](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss-reader) the master.